# My playbook is not working. I can't copy the file

Tags: ansible, centos, centos7, ansible-2.x

**Ansible host**:

- CentOS 6( 2.6.32-754.35.1.el6.x86_64)
- Python version 2.6
- Ansible version 2.6

**Test virtual machine**:

- CentOS 7 (CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core) 3.10.0-1160.11.1.el7.x86_64)
- Python 2.7.5

**how I added the user to the test server**:

```
groupadd -g 590 www
groupadd -g 591 playbookuser
adduser -u 690 -g 591 playbookuser
usermod -a -G www playbookuser
mkdir -p /home/playbookuser/.ssh/
echo "ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAA==">> /home/playbookuser/.ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 600 /home/playbookuser/.ssh/authorized_keys
chown -R playbookuser.playbookuser /home/playbookuser/
In /etc/sudoers addet "playbookuser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL"
```

then I create and run playbook:

```
---
 - hosts: all
   become: yes
   become_method: sudo
   gather_facts: no
   tasks:
     - name: backup sshd config
       copy:
         src: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
         dest: /etc/ssh/sshd_config.bak
         backup: yes
```

Ansible connects by ssh to the test machine and executes commands from the user playbookuser
Then the playbook will not work, what is the problem please tell me ?
PS. if you run the same command from the user in the console with the sudo prefix , then everything is ok.

but I get this error:

```
MSG:

an error occurred while trying to read the file '/etc/ssh/sshd_config': [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/etc/ssh/sshd_config'
  to retry, use: --limit @/var/lib/****/workspace/test_adm_deploy/174/backup_sshd%20_config.retry
```

Comment: You are trying to copy your local controller sshd config file to every remote target defined in your inventory. Your local user launching the playbook does not have access to that file. I suspect what you really want is to copy the remote file to a different location on the target machine. In this case use `remote_src: yes` in the copy module. But in such a case `backup: yes` is really an overkill IMO.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is listed in a comment.

remote_src: yes

Should be added.

backup: yes

Should be removed.